# Unable to load the driver. Error opening device /dev/scap0

Tags: drivers, kernel, 22.04, ubuntu-drivers

```
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)

Kernel: 6.2.0-1018-azure
```

I followed the sysdig [setup guide for linux](https://github.com/draios/sysdig/wiki/How-to-Install-Sysdig-for-Linux#user-content-manual-installation) but am not able to figure out how to resolve this.

Post installation, if I run `sysdig` or `sudo sysdig`;

```
Unable to load the driver error opening device /dev/scap0. Make sure you have root credentials and that the scap module is loaded: No such file or directory
```

It looks like scap kernal module is not loaded, but where do I get it from and load it?

Also, I did not get this issue when installing on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue. I ended up downloading Sysdig from github source https://github.com/draios/sysdig/releases.

After downloading and extracting the correct Sysdig version, go to file path `/home/user1/sysdig-0.34.1-x86_64/usr/bin` (the file path will vary based on your username and where you download and extract Sysdig) and you will find the `scap-driver-loader`, `sysdig` and `csysdig` files.

Run `sudo ./scap-driver-loader` to load the driver and finally run `sudo ./sysdig` to run sysdig.

Hope this helps.